# Adding a model object to a parent table

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a form where a someone enters a `network`, `location`, and `administrators` of the network. This is my model --

```
class Administrator(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

class Network(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    administrators = models.ManyToManyField(Administrator, blank=True)
```

How could I create a form such that when the site admin adds an administrator to a network, it will immediately create that entry in the `Administrator` class and then link up to that in the `administrators` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom processing of your form objects use `form.save(commit=False)`:

> This save() method accepts an optional
>   commit keyword argument, which accepts
>   either True or False. If you call
>   save() with commit=False, then it will
>   return an object that hasn't yet been
>   saved to the database. In this case,
>   it's up to you to call save() on the
>   resulting model instance. This is
>   useful if you want to do custom
>   processing on the object before saving
>   it, or if you want to use one of the
>   specialized model saving options.

from: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

---

So if you have a `NetworkForm` you could use `commit=False` and then check if your administrator already exists or if he needs to be created. [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) is really handy for this.

Then you could set `administrator` on your form to the newly created or fetched administrator-instance and save the form (using `form.save()` and `form.save_m2m()`).